# What are the time rules in Candidate Tournament?

Tags: rules, fide, tournament, candidates

So I'm following the London Candidate Tournament and I'm a bit confused regarding the time and why some games are getting an extensions and some are not and you are eventually losing because of time.

So my question is what are the exact rules on that matter for this tournament?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [the official rules](http://www.fide.com/FIDE/handbook/regscandidates2012.pdf), section 3.5: 120 minutes for the first 40 moves, 60 minutes for the next 20 moves and then 15 minutes for the rest of the game plus an additional 30 seconds per move starting from move 61.